# Why does NameNode HA use JournalNode instead of Zookeeper istself?

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

Looking at the following hdfs documentation makes me wonder why hadoop is using a JournalQuorum instead of using Zookeeper itself for keeping fsImage and EditLogs synchronized
      http://hortonworks.com/blog/namenode-high-availability-in-hdp-2-0/

In other words, whats the problem in using zookeeper service instead of a bunch of JournalNodes for active-standby NameNode communication.?

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be - Zookeeper is not meant for storage. If I remember correctly, the default maximum size of data that can be stored in a ZNode is 1 MB.

Comment: Edit Logs transactions are not that huge anyway right?

Comment: EditLogs themselves could add up to Gigs if they are not checkpointed. but each transaction is not huge. And zookeeper is used just as mediator to pass the transaction right?

Comment: if you consider say a periodic checkpoint of 1hr produces mere 50MB of edit transactions, I guess, it's still too much for Zookeeper to store in a ZNode. In the above architecture (by what I can infer) is just to monitor the two namenodes so that when one goes down, the other can take up the duty. Zookeeper is not used for any storing purpose it seems. In the architecture, I also don't see the checkpoint node that does a FSImage and Edit log merge. Could it be that the Journal nodes' doing the duty?